# Starting neo4j on mac

Tags: macos, neo4j

I'm trying to, unsuccessfully, start the neo4j server. I've followed the guide, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-installation.html#_mac_osx_service, but keep getting the following error:

```
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
 process [22112]... waiting for server to be ready......................................................................................................................... BAD.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it had already started, did a simple grep:

ps -eaf | grep ***

Comment: Did you get that error message from the `./bin/neo4j install` command or by running `./bin/neo4j start` right after an install? When you `grep`'ed for the process, did it report the same PID as the log message above (22112)? What Neo4j version? It would be really useful if you somehow provided access to the `data/log` directory contents.

Answer (score 2):

I was attempting to open multiple instances. Simple grep showed that the process was already running.

For reference some commands:

```
./bin/neo4j start 
./bin/neo4j restart
./bin/neo4j stop 
./bin/neo4j info
```

Answer (score 0):

I closed down my node servers and it fixed this problem.