# Starting neo4j (community edition) on MacOS from command line

Tags: macos, neo4j

I've installed the community edition of Neo4j on my Mac. I am able to start the server by clicking the Neo4JCE icon in the Applications directory -> selecting the DB location -> pressing "start".

I would like to perform a similar task from the command line, including data location selection, but can't find a way. Following is the contents of my `/Applications/Neo4j Community Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin`:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 myself  admin       476 Feb 21 16:27 .
drwxr-xr-x@  8 myself  admin       272 Jan 13 03:00 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 myself  admin        63 Feb 21 17:59 .dblocation
drwxr-xr-x@ 25 myself  admin       850 Jan 13 03:00 Neo4j-Management
-rw-r--r--@  1 myself  admin      1707 Jan 13 02:58 Neo4j-Management.psd1
-rw-r--r--@  1 myself  admin      3633 Jan 13 02:58 Neo4jImport.bat
-rw-r--r--@  1 myself  admin      3209 Jan 13 02:58 Neo4jShell.bat
-rw-r--r--@  1 myself  admin       112 Jan 13 02:58 install.properties
-rw-r--r--@  1 myself  admin       232 Jan 13 02:58 neo4j-community.vmoptions
-rw-r--r--@  1 myself  admin  67620822 Jan 13 02:58 neo4j-desktop-2.3.2.jar
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 myself  admin      3652 Jan 13 02:58 neo4j-import
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 myself  admin      3520 Jan 13 02:58 neo4j-shell
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myself  admin       332 Feb 21 17:56 openNeoTerminal.sh
drwxr-xr-x   3 myself  admin       102 Feb 21 16:27 ~
```

Note,  You might think that the current question [has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726754/starting-neo4j-on-mac?rq=1). However, the solution in the linked question was to use `neo4j` command which I can't find anywhere on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

You could install and update the Neo4j community edition through [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) on Mac Os X via `brew install neo4j`. That package manager takes care of the path settings, so that afterwards you can in fact start Neo4j via command line with `neo4j start`.

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but the installed package does have its benefits, so I would like to keep it

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j CE for macOS is packaged as executable jar file, in the picture above you could see the package name listed as 'neo4j-desktop-2.3.2.jar'

Run Command in the following order:

> cd /Applications/Neo4j\ Community\ Edition\ 3.1.5.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/
>   java -jar neo4j-desktop-2.3.2.jar

Rest remains same as you mentioned the start of your question. Select the database and click the start button.